# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'bindDom' of undefined

Tags: php, laravel, webpack, hammer.js

Am using **laravel-boilerplate** for my application and i  installed **hammer.js** using npm command. When i run **`npm run dev`** command the laravel-mix build is successful, but am getting an error like

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'bindDom' of undefined

in browser console.

I think the issue is related to **webpack javascript bundling**.  How can i fix this error?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: what's the laravel version ?

Comment: laravel version: 5.6.

Comment: can i see package.json ?

Comment: show only script part

Comment: "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",

Comment: oh im sorry i thought error occurred during the dev process. bindDom or something similar errors occur when you assign a element to js but that element doesn't load yet ot not exist. can i see the line that error occur ? (not the line in plugin but your code)

Comment: yeah i know, but if you using chrome dev tool you can see the trace back in the error, and your file should be there

Comment: actually that script was for revolution slider.. i included revslider.js file inlaravel app.js file.. then i build it using npm run dev, build was successful. then when am using " jQuery('#thm-rev-slider').show().revolution()" function in html file am getting this not a function typeerror.

Comment: i don't get it, it's `Cannot set property 'bindDom' of undefined` or  'not a function' error ? can u update your question

Comment: both of these errors are showing. jQuery('#thm-rev-slider').show().revolution() am including this function in a script tag just above body tag. the laravel build js file is included just above this script. so the order is ok right?. But still it is showing .show().revolution() is not afunction error. May be if this error is fixed, the binddom error will automatically get fixed.

Comment: can you add your code to codepen and send the link? (only your code)

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qKVLae

Comment: revslider is not an open source  plugin right ? it's not in npm

Comment: yes its not opensource..its include with html theme file.. and included that js file to app.js